When compiling a JS file which is using MongoDB client, Webpack is generating AWS SDK files
I am trying to build a simple Node.js app which would be using express.js as a server and MongoDB as the database.
I am using WebPack with following configuration to compile a file called index.js. This file in calls a method which uses the following import import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';.
Webpack Config File
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const isProduction = argv.mode === 'production';

  return {
    target: "node",
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
      filename: isProduction ? 'server.min.js' : 'server.js',
      path: path.resolve( './', 'dist'),
      clean: true, 
    },
    
    module: {
      // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#root
     rules: [
         {
             test: /\.m?js$/,
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             options:{
              presets:[
                "@babel/preset-env",
              ]
             },
             exclude: [
              /node_modules/,
            ]
         }
     ],
    },
    
  };
};

Package.json
{
  "name": "test-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config .configs/webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "latest",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

Screenshot of files which are getting generated

I have tried commenting all the code, but when I comment import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';, build stops generating AWS files.
Cannot find any documentation which would suggest its a required dependency.
